# Javascript not getting injected into page

Tags: plugins, javascript

I have been pulling my hair out for the past couple days trying to fix an issue that I simply can't seem to get around.

I've provided a file containing 4 files. The steps below will create an environment similar to mine, to replicate the problem.

https://gofile.io/d/Q4Uaiz

1. install inbox theme in Wordpress (found in folder '1 - themes') and activate it
2. install the plugin Advanced Custom Field (folder '2 - plugins') and activate it
3. In Advanced Custom Field, import Advanced Custom Field file provided in folder '3 - acf content'
4. In tools, import posts into wordpress from folder '4 - wp posts'

We now have the same environment.

If you click on an article in the sidebar, you'll see the right pane update with the article you clicked on. A read more button also appears.

If you click on read more, it will take you to a new page. On this page, you will see graphs displayed.

This is the problem: for some reason, I cannot display on the graphs on the preview pane (the one with the "Read More" button).
I have tried everything, but the Javascript is simply not being injected into the preview pane page, whereas it is in the single post page, and yet they both get their content from the same file, "content-single.php".

I would massively appreciate any help, as this is driving me crazy. Thanks a lot

Comment: I applaud the effort you've gone to to help us reproduce this, but I can't sit down and install all that just now. I guess this is really an Inbox theme issue, or whichever part of this provides the graph script (ACF?), or the combination of the two. It's possible the the plugin is trying to be clever to not load the graph rendering script unless it thinks it's needed, and by the time the sidebar is initialised and the content read into that it's too late to go back and add the script to the includes list

Comment: assuming that is the sidebar is rendered in PHP and not e.g. loaded via AJAX (I'd guess not?). But I would be surprised if the sidebar was rendered using content-single - that might end up with completely the wrong styles to fit things into the sidebar?